# Global caching mechanism in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I am creating dot net API service which will be hosted in web farm and accessed across multiple servers. This is an update envelope service and so I do not need multiple users updating the same envelope at the same time. Is there any way I can have a global cache or something like that which holds the current envelope being updated and throw an error when multiple users update the same envelope simultaneously? I tried locking mechanisms but looks like it works only for a single server system.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: You need to look into the distributed lock pattern. There are various ways to achieve this but seeing that you are mentioning caching I would suggest you look into https://redis.io, It can be used as a distributed cache and lock facility.

Comment: @JanusPienaar - Could you post your answer in the mail answer section? I am not able to give you the final solution when you post here

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you have to write your own locking mechanism.

Different servers are largely unaware of each other, even if they were to run on the same machine. You would have to have a central server that all your servers connect to and 'ask' if they can edit an envelope.
This is not going to be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you probably want to look into the ***Distributed Lock*** or [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) design pattern. There are a multitude of ways to achieve this functionality.

You mentioned Cache so I would recommend that you look into a [Distributed locks with Redis](https://redis.io/topics/distlock). Or if you are more familiar with something like RabbitMq you could use a [Distributed Semaphore](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/) in RabbitMq.